# How to apply weights to probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

I have a majority voting algorithm where there is a single voter with a probability $0.75$ of being correct and also 6 other voters that have a probably $0.6$ of being correct. Then I can determine the total probability by distinguishing two cases using the binomial distribution.

Either the single voter is correct and at least 3 of the other voters are correct:

$0.75 \cdot \sum_{x=3}^{6} \frac{6!}{6!(6-x)!}0.6^x \cdot 0.4^{6-x}$

Or the single voter is incorrect and at least 4 of the other voters are correct:

$(1 - 0.75) \cdot \sum_{x=4}^{6} \frac{6!}{6!(6-x)!}0.6^x \cdot 0.4^{6-x}$

The sum of those two is the total probability of the majority vote being correct.

Now this is all fine. But now what I would like to do is apply a weight to the single voter so it counts stronger. I now how I can do if there were concrete votes. Just make the vote counter more. But how can I achieve the same thing in terms of probabilities?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand precisely what you are trying to achieve.  Suppose we make the single voter's vote count as $2$ votes.  How can we tell if that is right or wrong?

Comment: @saulspatz We know the probability the single voter is correct $0.75$. So making that voter count stronger or weaker should impact the total probability.

Comment: Is making the weight of his vote equal to $2$ right or wrong?  Answer yes or no, and explain why or why not.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes it could be 2. But also 0.5. or 1.5 or 10 any non-negative real number.

Comment: You are asking us how to choose, but you wont tells us what makes one choice better than another.  This is impossible.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming voters are independent, you start with the probability of the majority being correct of $$0.75 \cdot \sum\limits_{x=3}^{6} \frac{6!}{6!(6-x)!}0.6^x \cdot 0.4^{6-x} + 0.25 \cdot \sum\limits_{x=4}^{6} \frac{6!}{6!(6-x)!}0.6^x \cdot 0.4^{6-x} = 0.75168$$
which is not much better than making voter $1$ a dictator $(0.75)$

You have seven voters:

- if you give voter $1$ less than a double weight then you will not affect majority decisions
- if you give voter $1$ a double weight (or a quadruple or sextuple weight) then you might get a tie, which is presumably not good news
- if you give voter $1$ between a double weight and a quadruple weight then voter $1$ and two others can outvote four other voters so your probabilities become $$0.75 \cdot \sum\limits_{x=2}^{6} \frac{6!}{6!(6-x)!}0.6^x \cdot 0.4^{6-x} + 0.25 \cdot \sum\limits_{x=5}^{6} \frac{6!}{6!(6-x)!}0.6^x \cdot 0.4^{6-x}=0.7776$$ which is slightly better
- if you give voter $1$ between a quadruple weight and a sextuple weight then voter $1$ and one other can outvote five other voters so your probabilities become $$0.75 \cdot \sum\limits_{x=1}^{6} \frac{6!}{6!(6-x)!}0.6^x \cdot 0.4^{6-x} + 0.25 \cdot \sum\limits_{x=6}^{6} \frac{6!}{6!(6-x)!}0.6^x \cdot 0.4^{6-x}=0.758592$$ which is worse
- if you give voter $1$ more than a sextuple weight then voter $1$ becomes a dictator and the probability is $0.75$ which is worse

Comment: Very clear thank you!